# SEC_TO_TIME function breaking within case function

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a case function within my select query. Within this case I want to convert "SongLength" which is in seconds into and mm:ss format with the `SEC_TO TIME` function. However I get a syntax error upon putting this function in there.

```
select SongTitle,Artist,SongLength
  case
       when SongLength < 600 then
            sec_to_time(SongLength)
       else
            sec_to_time(SongLength)
  end 
 from Songs, Artists where Songs.ArtistId = Artists.Id 
order by SongTitle;
```

Comment: share your sample data and what is the data type of SongLength

Comment: We can't really answer your question without seeing your data, and also what the exact error is.  Note that both branches of your `CASE` expression are the same thing; does this really make sense?

Comment: Missing comma after `SongLength` ... is this verbatim your query?  If so, then this explains the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Try `SongLength` to make an alias as :

```
select SongTitle,Artist,
(case
when SongLength < 600 then
    sec_to_time(SongLength)
else
    sec_to_time(SongLength)
end) as SongLength 
 from Songs join Artists 
  on ( Songs.ArtistId = Artists.Id ) 
 order by SongTitle;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok yours is another true approach.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hm nice and interesting, thanks. I see, my answer depends on an assumption in a way.

Answer (score 0):

see below  example works fine

```
select case
    when 400 < 600 then
        sec_to_time(400)
    else
        sec_to_time(300)
    end as col
```

it returns below output

```
     col
    00:06:40
```

So if your datatype of column SongLength is numeric then it should work

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/835f61/150

Comment: Believe it or not, `sec_to_time('400')` also works in MySQL, due to implicit conversion.  The error is being caused by a missing comma, or misplaced alias, depending on how you view it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks sometimes we do silly mistake and when we see different similar example it helps to reach to original issues that's  why i post this answer , so that OP can focus his thought in different dimension